# "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: post, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the token from **stripe** by submitting the stripe form.It gives me the error

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I already have tried with:

```php
@method('GET') // gives back the same page
@method('HEAD') // gives back an empty page
```

Here is my stripe form:

```
<form action="{{route('bill.payment')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_tjs3R2OtR8kbuis8IPNlOJAh008bBqanO5"
        data-amount={{Cart::total()}}
        data-name="Online Payment"
        data-description="E Commerce Website"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true">
      </script>
</form>
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('/bill/payment',[
'uses'=>'PaymentController@pay',
'as'=>'bill.payment'
]);
```

And my Controller:

```
 public function pay()
    {
        dd(request()->all());
    }
```

I expect the form data to die dump in my Controller.Any Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Are your routes cached](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#route-caching)?

Comment: my routes are not cached. But i just solved the issue.Thanks@Don't Panic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My **stripe** form is inside of another form.When i put my stripe form outside of the form it is working fine.Thanks to all.